# Style class A + class B AND class A only

Tags: less

I have the following setup at the moment

```
.classA {
  &.classB {

  }

  &.classC {

  }

  // some more 
}
```

So every class is dependent on classA. Not requirements changed and I need to have classB,c ... working outside of classA.

However, it's important that it's still connected to classA via &.

I'm looking for something like

```
.classA, {
  ... // the comma should indicate classA or nothing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The clean way would be

```
.classB {
  &, &.classA {
    // style here
  }
}
```

for every class